# Chrome Browser Ads Clicking

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have written this code

```
List<IWebElement> CountingAds = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@onmousedown='return google.arwt(this)']")).ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < CountingAds.Count; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000); CountingAds.ElementAt(i).Click(); driver.Navigate().Back();
                }
```

for clicking the Ads which appears while we search on the Chrome Browser but it just click the first Ad Successfully but next time it gives this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDl76.png)
someone help me out with this problem i am getting too frustrated guys.

Comment: I have posted an answer, let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting stale element reference exception, which comes when the element you are operating on is no longer present or is an old element and that's why it is working only the first time and not after that.
So to solve this problem, you need to fetch fresh element everytime after you click on one ad.
For example(i am using java so please convert the code to whichever language you are using):

```
List<WebElement> CountingAds = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@onmousedown='return google.arwt(this)']"));
CountingAds.get(0).click();
```

And now again fetch the webelement list and again click on the element like we did it by the above code. This would solve your problem.